# Adding an image border

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drawing, nsimage

OK, this is what I'm trying to do :

- Get an `NSImage` containing, let's say a photo (1000+ x 1000+ dimensions).
- Get another `NSImage` containing just a tranparent background and a simple black border (500x500).
- "Combine" the 2 images, so that the resulting image is the photo with a border.

This is what I've achieved so far :

```
NSImage* resultImage = [[[self drop] image] copy];
[resultImage lockFocus];

NSRect newRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, [[[self drop] image] size].width, [[[self drop] image] size].height);

[[[self drop2] image] drawInRect:newRect  
                        fromRect:NSZeroRect 
                       operation:NSCompositeSourceOver 
                        fraction:1.0];

[resultImage unlockFocus];

[[self drop] setImage:resultImage];
```

Where `[self drop]` is an ImageWell containing the photo, and `[self drop2]` an ImageWell containing the border.

The thing is that it IS working. However, **the resulting image is - quite obviously - showing a somewhat "stretched" border.**

[image: Image with Border]

How could I resolve that? Given that the original photo should be of ANY dimensions, how could I make it to use a border (of some fixed dimensions) and still avoid stretching?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing the border directly with `CALayer`, e.g.:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CALayer *layer = imageView.layer;
layer.borderColor = [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.borderWidth = 10;
```

Comment: This definitely **does** make sense. However, what if the border is an Image border and not just a simple black-line border?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this differently. Just size the image as desired and then add the border. You could do this just by having a simple view with black background, or a suitable image (assuming you want to have customizable image borders, like frames), sized to always keep the resulting border constant. Then you can generate a new image from that view, if you need to.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point : Why do I have to re-size the original photo/image? And what should the dimensions be? Could you please elaborate a bit more on the concept?

Comment: The point is to add the border based on the size of the image. `width += 2*margin; height += 2*margin; x -= margin; y -= margin;` Put a view with this size and position behind the image and voilà! you have a constant border width.

Comment: Wow. This sounds like a brilliant idea. Let me try this out and i'll let you know how it went... Thanks, mate! ;-)